# java selenium phantomjs can't locate element by xpath

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, single-page-application

The submitted code was written only for the proof of concept of usage PhantomJS with Selenium.

I'm testing a Single Page Application.

Code works fine with GoogleChrome and FireFox, but can't find element with PhantomJS.

The problem is that **driver finds "Login" button** on Landing page (by xpath) BUT throws a `TimeoutException:ExpectedCondition failed` after trying to locate element by `xpath` when user was redirected on Login form.

I'm using:

- Selenium 3.4.0
- PhantomJS 2.1.1

My Code:

```
public class GoogleSearchTest 
{

private WebDriver driver;
private WebDriverWait wait;

@Before 
public void SetUp()
{
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "./src/test/resources/drivers/phantomjs.exe");
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://dev.investmentpunk.academy");
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
}
@Test
public void testGoogleSearch() throws InterruptedException
{
    WebElement Login_btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[@class='ng-scope'][1]"));
    Login_btn.click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='c-input-db ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength']"))).sendKeys("user1");

    WebElement Password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-row'][2]/input[@class='c-input-db ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required']"));
    Password.sendKeys("qwerty");

    WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-blue']"));
    Login.click();
}

@After
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

Please, help me to solve this issue.

======================Edited part======================

So, the case is that I'm running the code with TestNG (or with JUnit), using Your xpathes and it worked, until yesterday. So, driver is unable to locate a `WebElement Login_btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[@class='ng-scope']/a[text()='EINLOGGEN']"));` I didn't provide any sugnificant changes in the code:

```
public class GoogleSearchTest 
{   
private WebDriver driver;
private WebDriverWait wait;

//second commit mess

@BeforeTest
public void SetUp()
{
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "E:/PhantomJS/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    System.out.println("=====PhantomJS Driver Initiated=====");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://dev.investmentpunk.academy/");
    System.out.println("=====URL Accessed=====");
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
}

@Test
public void testGoogleSearch() throws InterruptedException
{       
    WebElement Login_btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[@class='ng-scope']/a[text()='EINLOGGEN']"));
    Login_btn.click();
    System.out.println("=====EINLOGGEN button Clicked=====");

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username/Email']"))).sendKeys("user1");
    System.out.println("=====Username Sent=====");

    WebElement Password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Passwort']"));
    Password.sendKeys("qwerty");
    System.out.println("=====Password Sent=====");

    WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-blue']"));
    Login.click();
    System.out.println("=====Login button Clicked=====");
}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown()
{
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

[Fist error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdpAh.png)

[Second error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SXKB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

A few words about the Solution:

1. The `xpath` you have constructed includes indexes. So they are brittle and vulnerable.
2. Just like `class` attribute we can use `placeholder` attribute too.
3. You have used `@Before` and `@After` Annotations from `JUnit`, instead I have used `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` Annotations from `TestNG` and the below code block works fine:

   ```
   public class Q44928902_GoogleSearchTest 
   {

       private WebDriver driver;
       private WebDriverWait wait;

       @BeforeTest 
       public void SetUp()
       {
           System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "C:/Utility/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");
           driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
           System.out.println("=====PhantomJS Driver Initiated=====");
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.get("https://dev.investmentpunk.academy");
           System.out.println("=====URL Accessed=====");
           wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
       }
       @Test
       public void testGoogleSearch() throws InterruptedException
       {
           WebElement Login_btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[@class='ng-scope']/a[contains(@href,'/db/login/')][text()='EINLOGGEN']"));
           Login_btn.click();
           System.out.println("=====EINLOGGEN button Clicked=====");

           wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username/Email']"))).sendKeys("user1");
           System.out.println("=====Username Sent=====");

           WebElement Password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Passwort']"));
           Password.sendKeys("qwerty");
           System.out.println("=====Password Sent=====");

           WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-blue']"));
           Login.click();
           System.out.println("=====Login button Clicked=====");
       }

       @AfterTest
       public void tearDown()
       {
           driver.quit();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Here is the output of the code block:

   ```
   =====PhantomJS Driver Initiated=====
   =====URL Accessed=====
   =====EINLOGGEN button Clicked=====
   =====Username Sent=====
   =====Password Sent=====
   =====Login button Clicked=====
   [INFO  - 2017-07-06T09:58:41.996Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
   PASSED: testGoogleSearch

   ===============================================
       Default test
       Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
   ===============================================
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

---

### Update [07/13/2017 - 19:00 IST]

I have re-run the same code and here is the result:

```
Jul 13, 2017 6:56:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: C:\Utility\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe
Jul 13, 2017 6:56:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 13867
Jul 13, 2017 6:56:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=13867, --webdriver-logfile=C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\LearnAutomationTestNG\phantomjsdriver.log]
Jul 13, 2017 6:56:42 PM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
[INFO  - 2017-07-13T13:26:45.068Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 13867
[INFO  - 2017-07-13T13:26:46.224Z] Session [eb077d70-67ce-11e7-9bc6-6935b23fd504] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1","webSecurityEnabled":true}
[INFO  - 2017-07-13T13:26:46.224Z] Session [eb077d70-67ce-11e7-9bc6-6935b23fd504] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
[INFO  - 2017-07-13T13:26:46.224Z] Session [eb077d70-67ce-11e7-9bc6-6935b23fd504] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"2.1.1","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.2.0","platform":"windows-8-32bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2017-07-13T13:26:46.225Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: eb077d70-67ce-11e7-9bc6-6935b23fd504
Jul 13, 2017 6:56:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
=====PhantomJS Driver Initiated=====
=====URL Accessed=====
=====EINLOGGEN button Clicked=====
=====Username Sent=====
=====Password Sent=====
=====Login button Clicked=====
[INFO  - 2017-07-13T13:27:05.036Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
PASSED: testGoogleSearch

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@47caedad: 9 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@126253fd: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@1807f5a7: 246 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@415b0b49: 151 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 0 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@642a7222: 65 ms
```

Let me know exactly at which line you are facing the issue along with updating the full code & error stack trace in the Question area.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me.
And I found really interesting, how you build an xpath for web-elements.
Personally I use "XPath helper" plugin in Chrome.

Could you advise some resources, how to build xpathes which won't be "brittle" and "vulnerable"?

Comment: Great news !!! IMO, the biggest resource to learn is by reading others code and helping out others :) Thanks

Comment: Hello again!
I've faced the same problem again. (today)
Even with your advices, it stopped worked.

Now it can't even locate first element (Login_btn) by xpath

Can you please rerun your code? I just want to know, is this problem related to PhantomJS, or to web-application.

Comment: @DDenys Check out my update within my Answer. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for reply.
I've updated my post.(Edited part)

Comment: Check out my updated Answer. That too works well at my end. Thanks